# Git Rep Revision understanding

Tags: git

I had a lot of commits in Rep#1 (for example) and i immediately pushed all comits to remote GitHub. 
In some moment I found that I pushed passwords and logins from DB to remote server. I deleted all branch, created new and manualy copy all commits with marks in new branch. But after i killed old branch I found that first init commit on my forks tree became like an Appendage on Revision Graph (6ba8...). 
[image: First Rep]

[image: Second Rep]

Ok. I have created new Rep#2 and began copy all commits to it, but in my Revision Graph i also see the same picture: First commit (a128e) is like a Appendage, then i see arrow, then - Orgin/Head and then also black arrow and Master

My question is - Is it normal???

Comment: I think you will have to explain with simple examples (with git commands) what you meant with each step you did.

Comment: I always did the same:

`$git add .
$git add -u
$git commit -m 'message'
$git push -u orirgn master`

Comment: I think this is _the most important part_: `I deleted all branch, created new and manualy copy all commits with marks in new branch`. But I think showing us what you did on each step will be necessary to understand what you attempted.